# Haskell: Sort list

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, functional-programming

I am new to Haskell. Can I fix this recursive function **to sort all the integers in the array**? If yes, how should the code be?

```
isort [] = []
isort [x] = [x]
isort (x:y:xs) = if x <= y then 
                    x:isort (y:xs) 
                else 
                    y:isort (x:xs)
```

Input in current function

```
isort [4,3,2,1]
```

gives as output now

```
[3,2,1,4]
```

**But it should be**

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: You here put the smallest of the first two items as first element. But it is not said that this is the smallest list in the entire list.

Comment: in Data.List module you have several operations on lists, one of them is sort . https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:21

Answer (score 3):

Probably the smallest change to the code to let this sort a list is each time selecting the `mymin` of the list and yield this as first item of the result and recurse on the list, so:

```
mymin :: Ord a => [a] -> (a, [a])
mymin [x] = (x, [])
mymin (x:xs)
    | x <= y = (x, xs)  -- select a new minimum
    | otherwise = (y, x:ys)   -- use the minimum of the tail of the list
    where ~(y, ys) = mymin xs
```

then we can work with:

```
isort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
isort [] = []
isort xs = y : isort ys
    where (y, ys) = mymin xs
```

This is an implementation of [*selection sort* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) and thus runs in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. I leave it as an exercise to implement faster algorithms like *merge sort* and *Timsort*.

Answer (score 0):

Sort and insert one element in array

```
insert x [] = [x]
insert i (x:xs) = if i<=x then
                    i:x:xs
                else 
                    x:insert i xs
```

Loop insert function on the whole array

```
isort [] = []
isort (x:xs) = insert x (isort xs)
```